# Type 'UserStateModel' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, any>'

Tags: angular, ngxs

I do have an angular 15 App with NGXS as state management framework.

All works fine, even the method i post as a problematic here was working find and the error occurred without any manipulation on my side.

So :

I have an Interface, defining my user

```
export interface IUser {
  id: number;
  userId: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  practicants: IPracticant[] | [];
  practicant: IPracticant | null;

} 

export interface IPracticant {
  city: string;
  email: string;
id: string;

}
```

so the problem occurred when i tried to update the practicants in my IUser stateModel in ngxs

export type UserStateModel = IUser | null | undefined;

```
      @Action(ChangePracticants)
    changePracticants(ctx: StateContext<UserStateModel, { data }: ChangePracticants >
          ctx.setState(
            patch<UserStateModel>({. // UserStateModel does not satisfy....
              practicants: updateItem(
                (item: IPracticant) => item!.id === data.id,
                patch({
                  firstName: data.firstName,
                  lastName: data.lastName,
                })
              ),
    
              practicant: updatedPracticant,
            })
          );

}
```

Any Idea why this happens? All the interfaces and types are rightly connected

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to mention that IPracticant interface does contain first and last name

```
export interface IPracticant {
  city: string;
  email: string;
id: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string

}
```